# Executing a series of $timeouts

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS app. The app needs to alternate time outs. This alternating is handled by an array. The array looks like this `[3000, 1000, 3000, 1000, 5000]`.

This array means run an operation for three seconds. Then, wait one second. Then run another operation for three seconds. Then wait another second. Finally, run another operation for 5 seconds. The operations will differ. Either way, I'm not sure how to execute them in sequence.

How do I execute a series of $timeout elements in AngularJS?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean run something for 3s?  Do you run some calculation in a loop for 3s?  If you do that you'll lock up the UI for 3s.  What operation are you actually running for that time period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something that would be better done as a custom timer because you need to keep track of the time, not just delay an operation.

Somehow, you need to format your data where you have the amount of run and pause time for each operation. Something like this:

```
var operations = [{fun: oneFunction, wait: 1000, run: 3000}, {fun: twoFunction, wait: 2000, run: 5000];
```

Then you will need to handle those functions, running them for their respective times:

```
function handleOperations(operationArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < operationArray.length; i++) {
         var start = Date.now();
         if ((Date.now()-start) <= operationArray[i].run) {
             operationArray[i].fun(); //run while the timer is still going
         } else {
             //otherwise, wait for specified time
             var waitStart = Date.now();
             if ((Date.now()-waitStart) <= operationArray[i].wait) {};
         }
    }

}
```